# Java: Are chars " and \" the same?

Tags: java

Given:

```
char x = '"';
char y = '\"';
```

Are x and y equal?

Comment: Did you compile and try to print `x == y`?

Comment: Or would we rather curate the best repository of verified questions and answers the internet has ever seen? The question wasn't asked, so I asked it. Maybe I'm a novice user that doesn't know what a test framework is, and this is your opportunity to teach me.

Comment: I don't think we are in a hurry to race to the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[They are equal.](http://ideone.com/TqyTk) (the link executes the following test)

```
class foo{
    public static void main(String[] a){
       System.out.println('"' == '\"'); // prints true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I didn't feel like running code so I just googled...

[JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

...and if your javac doesn't conform then it's broken and not my fault :)

The keywords I used were "JLS" (for Java Language Specification) and "character literals" (because that's what `'?'` is).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        char x = '"';
        char y = '\"';
        boolean equal = (x == y);
        System.out.println("x == y ?" + equal);
    }
}
```

The output is `true`. Seems pretty conclusive.